# Sorting non numerical and numerical values in a data frame in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, lexicographic-ordering

I need help sorting non-numerical and numerical values in a data frame in `R`.
I have a data frame with 195 rows and columns with the following names:

`Country.name, Country.code, Birth.rate, Internet.users, and Income.Group`

My assignment is to create a new data frame consisting of the first 30 rows of the original one sorted by income group in ascending order, and followed by internet users in descending order.

Income group has the following categories:

`high income`, `upper middle income`, `lower middle income` and `low income`

`Internet.users` is numerical.

Please help!

Comment: In order to improve your chances for getting an answer read these guidelines about [how to ask on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(18)

# create sample dataset
df <- data.frame(Country.name = as.character(paste0("Country", 1:195)),
             Income.Group = sample(c("high income", "upper middle income", 
"lower middle income", "low income"), 195, TRUE),
             Internet.users = round(runif(195, 500, 1500),0))

# only take the first 30 entries
df <- df[1:30,] 

# make Income.Group a factor with appropiate order of levels
df$Income.Group <- factor(df$Income.Group, levels = c("low income", "lower 
middle income", "upper middle income", "high income")) 

# first order on Income.Group in ascending order, than on Internet.users in 
# descending order (by using -rank you reverse the Intern.users column)
df <- df[order(df$Income.Group, -rank(df$Internet.users)),]

# take a look at the first 10 rows
head(df, 10)

Country.name           Income.Group     Internet.users
12    Country12          low income           1487
1      Country1          low income           1420
19    Country19          low income           1259
3      Country3          low income           1248
24    Country24          low income           1037
15    Country15          low income           1014
23    Country23          low income            588
17    Country17 lower middle income           1324
26    Country26 lower middle income           1244
6      Country6 lower middle income           1197
```